# Is it possible to have multiple inline-edits in one jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, inline

I am using jqgrid version 4.6.0. Assume I have 2 columns, and I have 2 "Edit" button columns. On clicking one Edit button, only one column should be editable, on clicking the other edit button, the second column should become editable. Is this possible? I hope my question has enough information, if not please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry, my code is way too different from the way normal jqgrid is implemented, moreover, its restricted. An idea would suffice, I have been modifying jqgrid a lot.

Comment: Its not a issue, its a feature I need to implement.

Comment: Holding multiple rows editable means that the changes in the previously editable row are **not saved**, but the user can not understand this. Moreover one can interpret in different ways what you do. Which "Edit" button you use? Do you use `formatter: "actions"` or your custom formatter. How you use inline editing? For example, `formatter: "actions"` allows you to edit multiple rows by default.

Comment: Thanks, @Oleg. But I dont want to edit multiple rows. I want to edit multiple columns based on condition. I am not using formatter: "actions". I create buttons manually. On clicking button, the columns which have the "editable" property set to true, will become editable. Here I want only few columns to be editable on some condition. Hope I am explaining better now.

Comment: The most easy would be to implement your requirement after upgrading to [free jqGrid]() 4.13.0 - the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with the end of 2014 (after the changes of the license of Tony's fork). I implemented a lot of new features. One from there: `editable` property (in every column) can be defined as *function*. It allows directly implement your requirement in the way. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for more information. Only if you really can't upgrade to free jqGrid you should include your JS code.

Comment: Is free jqgrid really free? If so, please share the download link. Thanks @Oleg

Comment: @RustinCohle: Sorry, [the link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) was broken. You can click on "releases" and download any release. Moreover I host jqGrid on CDNs (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) and publish on npm, bower, NuGet and on WebJars (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)). Free jqGrid *can be used really for free* under MIT/GPL [licenses](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/LICENSE.md). One can contribute by donating (see the readme), but it's optional.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg I got it from NuGet. Thing is I have modified my 4.6.0 version so much, so is there a way to use both?

Comment: @RustinCohle: You should never ever modify source code of any Open Source library if you don't plan to make your own fork and to develop it. I fixed in free jqGrid *a lot of small bugs* already in the first version 4.8.0. You should never modify the code to include *new features*. Sorry, but you should just use existing callbacks instead of modification of the source code.

Comment: I agree, I am not allowed to make such decision. Thanks @Oleg. Assist me with this alone then, my last option: I am trying to update the colModel dynamically, is there a way to update colModel alone?

Comment: @RustinCohle: There are **many ways** to modify `colModel` dynamically. You should better post new question and to describe the problem more detailed. Do you load the information about the modification of `colModel` *asynchronously* (from the server, via Ajax)? What kind of modification you need to do (modify some property or to add/remove some `colModel` item)? You should just describe your problem on an example.